# Why capybara codes don't work with selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am new to `Capybara`. I have a question about why my `Capybara` doesn't work when I use it together with `Selenium Webdriver`.

This is my sample code:

```
Given(/^I am on the Youtube homepage$/) do
  # visit 'http://www.youtube.com'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to('http://www.youtube.com')
end

When(/^I search for "([^"]*)"$/) do |search_term|
  fill_in 'search_query', :with => search_term
  click_on 'search-btn'
end

Then(/^videos of large rodents are returned$/) do
  expect(page).to have_content 'Making Friends with a Capybara'
end
```

When I run it, it just open `Firefox` and go to `Youtube` homepage. But it gets error:

`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "search_query"`.

Everything works with `visit 'http://www.youtube.com'` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a driver, telling it to navigate to a page and then it's going out of scope so it's getting deleted.   the `visit` line works because it's using the current capybara driver which stays around between test steps.   Rather than creating a driver manually you should be registering a driver with Capybara and then specifying which driver to use for the specific test.  See [drivers](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers)

Since capybara sets up a selenium driver by default for use with firefox you can just do

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

somewhere before running your tests to make all your tests run using selenium with firefox, or since capybara registers selenium as the default javascript driver you can tag any scenarios you want to run in firefox with @javascript as shown [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber)

```
@javascript
Scenario: do something something
Given ...
```

Comment: @JamesDo  You tried what? setting default_driver or tagging your scenario?  Maybe you should update your original question to what you are now trying - and show the Scenario as well as the steps  (Also I'm assuming you removed the driver= and driver.navigate stuff and just went back to calling visit as you should be)

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I have set `default_driver = :selenium` in `features/support/env.rb` and tag `@Javascript` in feature file. However, like you have said, I create the new driver and it is a different session with the session created in @When keyword. So they can't recognize each other.

Comment: I don't fully understand whether this has fixed the issue for you or not, If it has please accept the answer